# Decoding ARP packets using jnetpcap library

Tags: pcap, packet-capture, icmp, spark-streaming, jnetpcap

The following error occured while trying to read packets using jnetpcap library. What could be the reason ?

```
ERROR actor.OneForOneStrategy: org.jnetpcap.protocol.network.Ip4java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jnetpcap.protocol.network.Ip4
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.CheckpointWriter.write(Checkpoint.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.doCheckpoint(JobGenerator.scala:259)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$start$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(JobGenerator.scala:76)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

But it was able to read some of the Tcp , Udp packets as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you get such error but I once wrote a really efficient piece of code for sniffing TCP/UDP and RTP packets using JnetPCap, you can find it on my GitHub repository under the "Lizardous" name:
https://github.com/Longhitano/main_projects/blob/master/Lizardous/src/j1/lizardous.java

Comment: This occured while decoding packets on sending them from kafka producer to kafka consumer .